# Property Type from variable

Tags: c#, class

consider the following class:

```
public class ShortName
{
    public string ValueString { get; set; }

    private Type ValueType { get; }

    public typeof(ValueType) Value
    {
        get
        {
            //do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

This isn't possible as typeof(ValueType) isn't recognized. Can anyone help me define the "Value" property type as the type returned by ValueType?

thanks

Comment: `typeof(ValueType)` is an expession of the type `Type`, not a type. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Consider using Generics or the Object type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be possible using generics.  Try:

```
public class ShortName<T>
{     
     public string ValueString { get; set; }      
     private Type ValueType { get; }      
     public T Value<T>  
     { 
         get {  return /*Something cast to a T */ ; }     
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is completely impossible.
If you think carefully about it, it doesn't make any sense in the first place.

Properties must have *compile-time* types; you're trying to define a property whose type is only known at runtime.
How would you be able to use the property?

Instead, you can either make an `object` property or use generics.

Comment: that makes sense.. I'm using the object property. I was trying to avoid casting. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you want but:

```
public Type Value
{
    get
    {
        return ValueType.GetType();
    }
}
```

Since `typeof(<anything>)` will return `Type`.

If this is not what you want, look into using `Generics`.

Comment: No; that's not what he wants.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ShortName<T>
{
    public string ValueString 
    { 
        get 
        {
            return Value.ToString(); // be aware of null ref here!
        }
    }
    private Type ValueType 
    { 
        get 
        {
            return typeof(T);
        }
    }

    public T Value
    {
        get; set;
    }
}
```